# Sitecore 8.1: Can I export data from email experience manager?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am working on the email experience manager in Sitecore. What I want is that I would like to extract the data into excel file after I have successful sent out email. I would like my team to do other analysis on data such as open rate, click rate etc.

Do anyone know whether there is a button to do so? As I cannot find the button and cannot search any answer online.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look on [Experience Extractor](https://github.com/Sitecore/experience-extractor) project. It allows you to extract experience data from Sitecore.